# Salesforce Oauth on client side

Tags: oauth2, authentication

I am trying to authenticate a client in my SPA via Salesforce Oauth all on the client side. Currently, I have been trying to implement the user agent flow and have been receiving many errors such as:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

Has any one successfully implemented salesforce Oauth all on the client side app?

Answer (score 0):

This might help to fix your current error. Normally when we are running localHost files from browsers (especially Chrome), it sets the origin as Null and overrides the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

Recommended Solutions

1. Host your client app on some temporary server and set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to "*"
2. Disable --disable-web-security argument in Chrome browser. You can find steps here 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome